# Magento 1 | Email Template | Get Default Store name instead of current

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1, email-templates

We need to show default store name in email footer instead of current store name already used in footer template:

```
<h5 class="closing-text">Thank you, {{var store.getFrontendName()}}!</h5>
```

*file: app/locale/en_US/template/email/html/footer.html*

Comment: We have temporarily used custom variable for this purpose

Answer (score 0):

Go to System > Configuration > General tab

You can add the store name here and if you having multiple store then select the store from "Current Configuration Scope:" and do the same[image]

Comment: We have different stores on our site. We need to show only default store name within email regardless of email is generated for any store.